# An order-3 projective plane of English words

Tags: combinatorics

Here's a puzzle, definitely amenable to computer solution.

I'd like a set of 13 4-letter English words whose letter-sets form a projective plane.
So:
1) 13 letters are used in total
2) to make 13 words
3) each word is made of 4 distinct letters
4) each letter occurs in 4 distinct words
5) each pair of words have exactly one letter in common
6) each pair of letters occur jointly in exactly one word

Concrete nouns are preferred.

Is this possible, what sets can you find?

Comment: Hm, my BE+AE dicts have 2393 candidate words ...

Comment: The letters in an English word occur in a certain order. I'm afraid this order will be lost when the word is embedded in your projective plane. To put it differently: The lines are four element subsets of $\{{\tt A}, {\tt B},\ldots, {\tt Z}\}$ that can be arranged to form a word of the English language.

Comment: Question about this finite projective plane: Say there are $n$ vowels among the 13 letters (ignore the ambiguous nature of _y_).  What can we say about how many words there would be with 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4 vowels?  (I'm sure this is not uniquely determined, but can anything interesting be said about this "distribution"?)

Comment: (cont'd) In particular, is there some "Ramsey" style result that says there must be a 4-vowel word, or a 4-consonant word?  If that is true, then one idea might be to first find some English words made of 4 vowels / 4 consonants.  (Ideally that is _not_ true, and we can have each of 13 words having 1-3 vowels, as there are many more English words like that.)

Comment: @antkam, to avoid having any 4-vowel or 4-consonant word it's necessary to have 6 vowels, but Y should probably count as a vowel for these purposes, so it's possible.

Comment: Using the wordlist at http://www.allscrabblewords.com/4-letter-words/ (4003 words, which after filtering for duplicates gives 2070 sets of four letters) I can't fit more than 10 letters into the projective plane.

Comment: Thank you,that's more or less what I thought.  I had started trying to do this by hand, and always got stuck at some point.

Comment: if this is indeed impossible, i wonder what rule we can relax.  e.g. what if we allow a minimum (hopefully only 1) of the 13 words to be non-words?  if we're lucky the non-word might turn out to be a well-known acronym like IMHO :)  alternatively what if we allow a letter (e.g. E) to repeat, but the two versions are colored differently and count as two different letters?  that would add a lot of flexibility.

Comment: @PeterTaylor do you mind sharing the code?  i can think of many stupid ways to try all the possibilities but would love to see some smart ways.

Comment: BTW here is a consolation prize for order-2: JOY, JET, JAR, AYE, TRY, OAT, ORE

Comment: @antkam, it's not production-quality code. Basically it uses one heuristic: pick the point which has fewest possibilities for the letter. https://gist.github.com/pjt33/82330eabf2aad10fd049f284be8b5e7b